# Can't show "choose account" form in google signin in flutter ios app

Tags: ios, flutter, google-signin

Can someone help please?

I integrated google signin in my app and all works fine, but I get "email-password" form in auth popup all times although I have a lot of google accounts. In other apps this accounts show.

Code

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    ],
  );

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      print(account.email);
      print(account.id);
      print(account.displayName);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

I use

```
google_sign_in: ^4.0.14
```

I get

[image]

I would like to get [image]

Comment: did you find a solution?